# Wired Connection not detected on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which was working fine few days ago. Solution for "wifi disabled by hardware switch on Dell xps"

Tags: 12.04, wireless, connection, lan, wired

This working and not working happens to me often, and I dont know, why this is happening. I am frustrated trying all the related threads but it couldnt solve my problem. This wired lan connection is working fine on Windows 7.

I have made all pssible edits of `/etc/network/interfaces` , but no success
Please help. I dont know what all this etho, lo , stuff means
Why is this problem on Ubuntu 12.04 but not on Windows?

currently, my `/etc/network/interfaces` has

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

On running `ifconfig`, it gives :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:fe:b5:c5:a2:0d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:47 

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:fe:b5:c5:a2:0d  
          inet addr:169.254.8.129  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:47 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2022 (2.0 KB)  TX bytes:2022 (2.0 KB)

pan1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:f9:3a:a8:a6:ca  
          inet addr:10.63.169.1  Bcast:10.63.169.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::44f9:3aff:fea8:a6ca/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:15665 (15.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 88:53:2e:10:f8:24  
          inet addr:10.132.238.81  Bcast:10.132.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8a53:2eff:fe10:f824/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14890 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1886759 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:207660 (207.6 KB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..I realized what the problem is... it is because of a loose connection in my lan port (a little loose lan wire), Ubuntu 12.04 couldn't recognize my lan wire, but surprisingly Windoes 7 recognizes without any problem... I dont understand this , though. When I replaced my lan wire, with a nice tight one, Ubuntu recognized it instantly...

Somebody can please throw a light on this.

Also , I want to answer about a kind of solution for 'wifi disabled by hardware switch on Dell xps' but i couldnt as i my reputation is low.
So, I am asnwering it here.

There are many opinions in the forums, like:
you can get your wifi enabled on Dell xps (where one doesnt have a separate hardware switch)
1) Fn + F2 
2) Alt + Fn + F2 
3) changing ssomething in the /etc/network/interfaces file

I have tried these all, but these wont work all the time...

but for me, what works all the time on my Dell xps L502x is:
CLICK ON THE STAR BUTTON ON THE RIGHT TOP CORNER ON UR DESKTOP AND CLICK on 'SUSPEND'
then, IMMEDIATELY, WAKE UP FROM THE 'SUSPEND' MODE
and , then DO 'Fn + F2' one or two times...
Then wifi gets enabled on my laptop without any fuss whatsoever
I accidentally figured this out. had I figured it years ago, I would have saved myself of lot of torture about wifi connectivity problems

Hope this helps many other people like me, who was frustrated for about 1 and half years with this problem, but beleive me, I absolutely don't have a problem now